# How to execute an update statement with where clause having select statement

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (student) with the following schema in postgres 9.5:

```
  id          |   marks     |    division   | class
   1                90              A          1
   2                90              B          2
   3                90              B          1
```

I want to update divisions of student with class 1 and marks = 90 to "A".

I know I can simply use `update student set division='A' where class =1 and marks=90`

But this to understand how to use a select statement returning multiple rows in the query. Somethig like:

`update student set division ='A' where id=(select id from student where class=1 and marks=90)`

I am new to postgres. Some pointers will help.

Comment: `WHERE id IN (SELECT id ....)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a sub-select:

```
update student
   set division = 'A'
where class = 1 
  and marks = 90;
```

But if you insist on using a sub-select you need an `IN`:

```
update student
   set division = 'A'
where id in (select id 
             from student 
             where class = 1 
               and marks = 90);
```